# Development (CSS/HTML) - Find/highlight/outline divs with zero height

Tags: javascript, web-development, web-browser

I'm a web developer. And when a container contains floated elements this means that they won't affect the height of their parent (the container). To fix this issue you need to either add overflow: auto, overflow: hidden or use a clearfix. Sometimes I forget to add this and as a result causing bugs that are found late in the development process causing a high amount of time spent on troubleshooting.

So, I'm trying to find something to integrate with my workflow that allows me to easier see if I have missed to clearfix any container who only have floated children (i.e find div element who has 0 height).

I am either looking for a JavaScript tool that can be used with either Grunt or Gulp and give indication that a container on a certain line will have 0 height. Or a Browser extension that can highlight or outline all divs with 0 height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of ways to do this.  I am a big fan and heavy user of `gulp`, so normally I would recommend that, but in this case I think it's gonna end up being more trouble than it's worth:

I think your best here is to write a small function to execute on page load.

Something like the following:

```
    // pass it a selector like `div` or 
    // `classname` or `*`
     // the `el` parameter can be ignored 
     // unless you want to limit the search scope

  function testElemHeight(selector,el){
      if(!el){
        el=document;
      }
     var height;
     var $elems=el.querySelectorAll(selector);
    $elems=Array.prototype.slice.call($elems);
     $elems.forEach(function(elem,index){
         height=getComputedStyle(elem).height;
            if(height===0){
               // put your code in here
               // style it, or log it to the console
               // you have the `index` to use for reference
            }
       });
     }
```

Then execute the function with your desired selector on the `domready` event that your browser supports.

This will be easier than trying to modify your `gulpfile` or `gruntfile` and add code for this.